# Slideshow divs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs into another one which has `id="container"`. What I want is the page to start with first div from container then clicking on a next button to clear the div and show second div from container.

My code:

```
$(document).ready( function() 
{ 
   $("#container div").not("#container div:first").each(function(){

    $(this).addClass('hidden');

});

$("next").click(function(){
    var divWithoutHiddenClass=$("#container div").not("#container div.hidden");       

   divWithoutHiddenClass.addClass('hidden');

       if(divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html()===undefined){
           $("#container div:first").removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else{
        divWithoutHiddenClass.next().removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
});
```

and:

```
<div id="container" class="thirdcanvas">

       <div id="vapor">
           <img src="images/alfabet/w.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/f.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/v.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/o.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/r.png" alt=""/>
       </div>

       <div id="baiat">
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/aa.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/t.png" alt=""/>
       </div>     

       <div id="colac">    
           <img src="images/alfabet/g.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/c.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/u.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/o.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/c.png" alt=""/>
       </div> 

       <div id="slapi">    
           <img src="images/alfabet/s.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/ss.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/i.png" alt=""/>
       </div>  

       <div id="umbrela">   
           <img src="images/alfabet/u.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/n.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/m.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/p.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/b.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/r.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/e.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/l.png" alt=""/>
           <img src="images/alfabet/a.png" alt=""/>
       </div>  
   </div>

<a href="#" onClick="nextImage()"><img id="next" src="images/nextBtn.png" title="Continuare" /></a>
```

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for creating questions, specially about javascript. It saves everone time

Comment: this is it : http://jsfiddle.net/rQb5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytihng looks fine except of click exent change `$('next')` to `$('#next')` remove onclick arrgument on a tag and add there `id="next"`. If you don't want browser window to move on click you can also use prevent default on a click http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

more info if you will add jsfiddle :)

EDIT: because you added jsfiddle I am giving the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/rQb5e/16/

Comment: Please see that I am not using `not` pseudoclass. Because of that it's more brwoser compatibile. Unfortunately because of that we need to use another class

Answer (score 1):

In this line `$("next").click(function(){`
you missed the sharp ("#") before the img's id.
Also, i'm not sure that this is your all JS - code, but you wil see error that function "nextImage()" isn't defined.

I offer you to use jQuery function for show() and hide() instead of classes. I change your js code and worked is:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
           $("#container div").not(":first").each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $("#next").click(function(){
            var divWithoutHiddenClass=$("#container div").not(":hidden"); 
            divWithoutHiddenClass.hide();
            if (divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html() === undefined){
                $("#container div:first").show();
            }
            else{
                divWithoutHiddenClass.next().show();
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT: Example in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Erxa/

Comment: Yeah,it works great...now i only miss a contor for that coz it takes again the first div and i need to keep the last one...could you can help me?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your request. You mean that when visible div is the last and click "Next" - to show again the first div, right? If this is the problem - check my demo in fiddle.

Comment: Nope,there are 5 images and 5 divs...i have function to show em 1 by one untill 5th (both same time) ,but...after 5th div ,if i click next it show me the 1st div and i dont need to.I want the last div to remain there

Comment: If you doesn't want to move from 5th to 1st <div>, replace `divWithoutHiddenClass.hide();
            if (divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html() === undefined){
                $("#container div:first").show();
            }
            else{
                divWithoutHiddenClass.next().show();
            }`
with `if (divWithoutHiddenClass.next().html() !== undefined){ divWithoutHiddenClass.hide(); divWithoutHiddenClass.next().show();}`

Am I understand you right?

Answer (score 1):

I made an example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IQumIFO/4/edit), hope this helps. Don't know what you mean with "clear" in my example it randoms, when the last`<div>`is reached, it starts over with the first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i figurate it out with @user1278667 and Maciej Paprocki